# Workflow error 'ActionBranchingNot Satifisted

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, error, power-automate, flow

Can you explain to me this error am getting on my workflow:

> 'ActionBranchingConditionNotSatisfied. The execution of template action 'Send_an_email_(V2)' skipped: the branching condition for this action is not satisfied.'

I have created a ticketing system in SharePoint with Power automate flows, I need the closed tickets to move into another list which is created. But I cannot see where am going wrong.

Please help.

Comment: Did you add send an email action inside "Condition" action? If yes, expression/condition used in "Condition" action should result in `true` to execute the actions (like send an email) inside it.

Comment: Set up a trigger for when an item is created or modified in your SharePoint list and add a condition to check the status of the ticket. Based on this condition, create an item in the second list with the details from the current item, then you can delete the item from the original list.